# How to create horizontal scroll using css flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to create a webpage with a section that scrolls horizontally using flexbox. However, the code results in each box being reduced in size to fit the screen, rather than overflowing and enabling for horizontal scrolling.

Code:

```css
.main {
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.portfolio_item {
  width: 50%;
}

.flex {
  display: flex !important;
  display: -webkit-flex !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="main flex">
  <div class="portfolio_item willow">
    <a class="link" href="https://aubergewillowinn.com/">
      <div class="filter flex">
        <h3 class="portfolio_item-text">Willow Inn</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio_item bellevue">
    <a class="link" href="http://www.bellevuemtl.com/">
      <div class="filter flex">
        <h3 class="portfolio_item-text">Bellevue Condominiums</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio_item willow">
    <a class="link" href="https://aubergewillowinn.com/">
      <div class="filter flex">
        <h3 class="portfolio_item-text">Willow Inn</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio_item bellevue">
    <a class="link" href="http://www.bellevuemtl.com/">
      <div class="filter flex">
        <h3 class="portfolio_item-text">Bellevue Condominiums</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of putting your `.main` to `100%`, you can go higher than that, try a value like 200% or 250%

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add a min-width of 50% (as well as the width of 50%) to your child portfolio items, your code works (with overflow and scrolling).

Hope this helps

```css
.main {
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.portfolio_item {  
  min-width: 50%;
  width:50%;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="main flex">
  <div class="portfolio_item willow">
    <a class="link" href="https://aubergewillowinn.com/">
      <div class="filter flex">
        <h3 class="portfolio_item-text">Willow Inn</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio_item bellevue">
    <a class="link" href="http://www.bellevuemtl.com/">
      <div class="filter flex">
        <h3 class="portfolio_item-text">Bellevue Condominiums</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio_item willow">
    <a class="link" href="https://aubergewillowinn.com/">
      <div class="filter flex">
        <h3 class="portfolio_item-text">Willow Inn</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio_item bellevue">
    <a class="link" href="http://www.bellevuemtl.com/">
      <div class="filter flex">
        <h3 class="portfolio_item-text">Bellevue Condominiums</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I concur with @MaximillianLaumeister on this one however, flex is probably not the ideal choice if this is the desired output

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure flexbox is actually the tool for this job. The premise behind flexbox is that your elements **flex** to **fit inside the box**. However, you specifically want them to overflow your box, not fill the available space in your box.

[From css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

> The main idea behind the flex layout is to give the container the ability to alter its items' width/height (and order) to best fill the available space [...] A flex container expands items to fill available free space, or shrinks them to prevent overflow.

It might make more sense to enable horizontal scrolling by using a layout based on `inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap` like this:

```css
.main {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.portfolio_item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="portfolio_item willow">
    <a class="link" href="https://aubergewillowinn.com/">
      <div class="filter flex">
        <h3 class="portfolio_item-text">Willow Inn</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio_item bellevue">
    <a class="link" href="http://www.bellevuemtl.com/">
      <div class="filter flex">
        <h3 class="portfolio_item-text">Bellevue Condominiums</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio_item willow">
    <a class="link" href="https://aubergewillowinn.com/">
      <div class="filter flex">
        <h3 class="portfolio_item-text">Willow Inn</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio_item bellevue">
    <a class="link" href="http://www.bellevuemtl.com/">
      <div class="filter flex">
        <h3 class="portfolio_item-text">Bellevue Condominiums</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe change 'overflow' to 'overflow-x'. In some browsers, you automatically get a scrollbar both horizontal and vertical if you set 'overflow: scroll'.

Comment: @Tim Good idea, and done. I also changed it to `auto` so the scrollbars only show up when needed.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister I like using flexbox because it simplifies changing from mobile view where everything stacks vertically to desktop view.

Comment: @S.Miller I appreciate that, but in this case your code is going to be simpler and less hacky if you don't use flexbox. It's just not built for what you're trying to do here. To accommodate all screen sizes, I might recommend making a media query that switches between the `inline-block` and `flex` layouts depending on the width of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if using flex is necessary, since flex is to help avoid the overflow situation amongst other things.

[Here is a very simple example without flexbox](https://codepen.io/broderickdevelopment/pen/WgqVzK) utilising the `overflow-x: scroll;` and `white-space: nowrap;` attributes. The first allows the div to be scrollable, and the second prevents white space from wrapping around to a new line

```css
.container {
 overflow-x: scroll;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.box {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin: 5px;
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```